# Qual o comportamento da propriedade "order" quando não definida?

Tags: css3, flexbox, order

**Meu objetivo é o seguinte:**

O site possui uma área de compra que exibe 3 diferentes planos. Quando esta área de planos é acessada em uma tela maior do que 800px de largura, ela é exibida da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Os planos ficam dispostos um ao lado do outro.**

Porém, quando a tela for menor do que a largura anteriormente dita (800px), eu preciso que a ordem dos planos seja alterada: o plano **OURO** precisa aparecer em primeiro, o **PRATA** em segundo e o **COBRE** em terceiro.

**O problema:** *(recomendo que pulem direto para a parte do `@media` que é onde se encontra a propriedade `order` e também é onde o problema está)*

```css
.preco {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    padding: 60px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-end;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.preco-item {
    flex: 1 1 260px;
    border: 4px solid white;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.preco-item h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #a4a4a4;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.preco-item span {
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 0 5px 0;
    border-top: 4px solid white;
    border-bottom: 4px solid white;
}

.preco-item sup {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.preco-item ul {
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #7c7c7c;
}

.preco-item li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.preco-item li::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: #2c70ff;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.preco a {
    max-width: 300px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 4px solid;
    color: #222222;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.25em;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .preco {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .preco .preco-item:nth-child(3) {
        order: 0;
    }

    .preco .preco-item:nth-child(2) {
        order: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="preco" id="preco">

        <div class="preco-item">

            <h2>Cobre</h2>

            <span><sup>R$</sup>19</span>

            <ul>

                <li>Planos Ilimitados</li>
                <li>Acesso Restrito</li>
                <li>Conteúdo Secreto</li>
                <li>Suporte 24h</li>
    
            </ul>

            <a href="#">Comprar</a>

        </div>

        <div class="preco-item">

            <h2>Prata</h2>

            <span><sup>R$</sup>39</span>

            <ul>

                <li>Planos Ilimitados</li>
                <li>Acesso Restrito</li>
                <li>Conteúdo Secreto</li>
                <li>Suporte 24h</li>
                <li>Compra Exclusiva</li>
    
            </ul>

            <a href="#">Comprar</a>

        </div>

        <div class="preco-item">

            <h2>Ouro</h2>

            <span><sup>R$</sup>79</span>

            <ul>

                <li>Planos Ilimitados</li>
                <li>Acesso Restrito</li>
                <li>Conteúdo Secreto</li>
                <li>Suporte 24h</li>
                <li>Compra Exclusiva</li>
                <li>Download dos Items</li>
    
            </ul>

            <a href="#">Comprar</a>

        </div>

    </section>
```

No meu entendimento:

- Se o **terceiro** filho recebe `order: 0;`, ele passa a ficar em **primeiro** lugar.
- Se o **segundo** filho recebe `order: 1;`, este passa a ficar em **segundo** lugar.
- E o **último**, que não foi declarado, ficaria, logicamente, na **terceira** posição. Mas não é o que acontece.

Eu sei que se eu declarar, especificamente, um terceiro `:nth-child()` e colocar `order: 2;` o layout passa a responder da forma que eu quero. Apenas quero entender melhor a lógica do por quê ele não assumir automaticamente o valor do próximo elemento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A grosso modo **todos os elementos dentro e um container Flex são `order: 0`** . Então mesmo para o elemento que você não declarou explicitamente `order: 0`, ele é `order: 0` por padrão.

Um detalhe é que você pode usar valores negativos para o `order`, então se você quer o **Ouro** em primeiro, pode por exemplo colocar `order: -1` nele, então ele pula para a primeira posição, pois é menor que `0` :D. E no **Cobre** vc coloca `order: 1;` e ele vai para o final da lista, pois o **Prata** já é `order: 0` por padrão como falei.

---

**Agora uma dica sagaz!**

Não precisa de order nos filhos para fazer isso, basta mudar o `flex-direction` do pai para `row-reverse` que a ordem dos filhos será invertida!

```css
.pai {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<p>Pai flex com row-reverse<p>
<div class="pai" style="flex-direction: row-reverse;" >
  <div class="box">1 - OURO</div>
  <div class="box">2 - PRATA</div>
  <div class="box">3 - COBRE</div>
</div >

<p>Pai flex com SEM row-reverse<p>
<div class="pai" >
  <div class="box">1 - OURO</div>
  <div class="box">2 - PRATA</div>
  <div class="box">3 - COBRE</div>
</div >
```

Comment: Resposta simplesmente perfeita! Tanto a explicação quanto a dica. Não tinha nem passado pela minha cabeça alterar a ordem dos flex items usando o flex-direction. Muito obrigado <3

Comment: @RicardoPassos que bom que deu certo ai, fico feliz em ter ajudado, tmj